# Migrate from WCF to node.js

Tags: wcf, node.js, migration

At the moment, I write a WCF Service that gives the following functionality:

- Videoupload and -download
- Usermanagement
- Groupmanagement
- Filemanagement
- A forum
- Presencemanagement

As database I use a SQL Server 2012 from Microsoft.

The service gets called via REST, so this would not be the problem.

My question is, what advantage can I get with node.js or better said, is there any advantage?

The biggest advantage is in my point of view, that I am fully platform indipendent. Are there any other advantages?

Greets Knerd

**Update, I posted a new question here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188926/migrate-wcf-to-node-js**

Comment: The question isn't REST or WCF. The service runs on REST. The question is, if there are any advantages to use node.js.

Comment: Sorry. Misread part of it. But, my first point still stands -- generalized "*this or that*" questions like this aren't typically [on-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's not usually possible to answer them objectively and without conjecture. Though, if you can be more specific than "[*WCF or Node.js?*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)" and detail your requirements, then it might be a decent fit for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or another site in the [SE network](http://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks, then I will put the question to StackExchange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the usual advantages and disadvantages Node.js has.

I.e.:

- Platform independence
- Everything is asynchronous
- You have the same language for the backend as for the HTML frontend
- ...

Basically, the question whether you can benefit from Node.js IMHO comes down to whether you need to scale pretty much, and if you have lots of I/O to do.

If the answer to both is 'yes' then Node.js may be a pretty good catch for you.

PS: Completely off-topic, but - are you *Knerd* from the discussion forum of winfuture.de?

Comment: Yep I am ^^ How did you noticed? The answer to the questions are yes and no, scaling isn't so important, but I/O is very much, caused by the video management. I decided to build the licenseserver with node.js, this seems to be a good start to test how useful it is.

Comment: Well, when I read your question the name sounded familiar. Although I don't write there I often read comments by you and somehow remembered your name ;-)